# Optimal estimation using two measurement

Tags: estimation

Let's say I have 2 measuremnts of the same thing (for example current temperature) and I want to find the MMSE estimator, i.e to minimize the MSE.
the measurements are independent and the noise in each one is gaussian.
the mathematical formation:

$$ Y_1[n] = X[n] + V[n]$$
   $$ Y_2[n] = X[n] + W[n]$$

X[n] is the real temperature at time n

Y1[n] and Y2[n] are the measurements at time n

V[n] and W[n] are normally distributed random variables which represent the noise
$$ V(0,\sigma_v^2) $$
$$ W(0,\sigma_w^2) $$

I need at clue or reference for how to solve it

Thank you

Nir

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Comment: thank you. what do you mean by showing some effort?